# Check The ProductCode of An Installed Application

Tags: windows, product-id

How to check the [ProductCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370854(VS.85).aspx) for an installed application on Windows?

Answer (score 2):

[Belarc Advisor](http://www.belarc.com/free_download.html)... highly recommend...install it, run it, and the keys for all software should be near the end...

> Runs on Windows 7, 2008 R2, Vista, 2008, 2003, XP, 2000, NT 4, Me, 98, and 95. Both 32-bit and 64-bit Windows is supported.